# Is an open ball a complete metric space?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Is an open ball $K((0,0),1) \subset \Bbb R^2$ with maximum metric a complete metric space?

While I believe I understand basic metric space concepts I just don't have an idea how to prove or disapprove the statement, seeing an example I could deduce what should  I do in all the similar tasks.

Comment: Definitions are your friends.  What is required for a metric space to be complete?  Hint: Cauchy sequences.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: is $(1-1/n,0)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ Cauchy with the maximum metric? (Why *this* sequence?)

Comment: and if it is, then is its limit in the open ball ?

Comment: @TomCollinge, the trick is taking a sequence that converges to a point in the border.

Comment: I believe it is Cauchy with a limit in 1, and as it is an open ball then 1 doesn't belong to it. Am I thinking correctly? If so, then why the sequence is defined this way?

Comment: @BartoszS, right. See my previous comment. The trick is taking a sequence converging to a point that isn't in the space.

Comment: Ok, I see now. Were my other statements true though? And in that case is it ever possible for an open ball to be a complete metric space?

Comment: If you have time I'd also like to know if the sequence would be different in case of open ball with another metric.

Comment: Sorry for bothering you but I would really appreciate a short answer.

Comment: @BartoszS, take a bijection ball$\longrightarrow\Bbb R^2$ and compose with the the usual metric of $\Bbb R^2$. The ball will be complete with this metric.